# Running file through a program with arguments

Tags: java, batch-file, command, arguments, command-line-arguments

My issue here is that I can't seem to pass arguments through my program. I'm not sure how to explain it clearly but here it goes:

I want to be able to run a script file through a custom interpreter with arguments.

For example:

`AtomScript.exe main.atom -> Program runs`

When I want to run it through a batch file:

`main.atom -> Program runs`

Now when I want to pass arguments through the program using the AtomScript command in a batch file:

`AtomScript.exe main.atom arg1 arg2 -> Program runs with arguments`

The arguments are passed. But when I want to use the simple main.atom command to run it with arguments it doesn't work:

`main.atom arg1 arg2 -> Program runs without arguments`

I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.atom` is not an executable, so it can't take any parameters

Windows knows, which program has to be started and does so (ignoring any parameters)

Only if you start the executable directly, you can define parameters (the first one being `main.atom`)

for example:

```
C:\>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile

C:\>ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

`assoc` defines, what filetype that extension is ("txtfile")

`ftype` defines, what has to be done for this filetype (start notepad)

You can see, there is just one parameter `%1` (the filename (`main.atom`)).
Of course you could expand it with more parameters (needs to be run as administrator):

```
ftype txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %*
```

(which makes not much sense with this example), but I don't recommend it (it's just done on your computer). Better use the "official way": in the batchfile do exactly the same as on the commandline: start the executable with the desired parameters:

```
AtomScript.exe main.atom arg1 arg2
```

Comment: So I have to put quotes around %* ?

Comment: ah - good catch. If you put quotes around it, it's just a single argument. I removed them from my example (downside: no parameter with spaces is possible any more). But again: this is not recommended - use it carefully and wise.

Comment: is there anyway to make a file an executable?